# How to get started with a lawn makeover

Tags: diagnosis, lawn, soil, pest-control

I shifted to new house last year and garden is a mess, now the time is good and sun is good. I wanted to find out how can I make my garden a lush green which is habitat to sitting in the sun/playing. I.e play down compost and plant grass but don’t know where to start. 
Typically in my last house I would take the weed out (here I don’t know what is weed n grass) and fill in compost with putting grass plants around. Is that still the right way? Following are my garden picture

The last picture has a bed of wood. That was a shed but due to mice and rats no one is touching the base. My wife told me to cover/bury in under compost but I wanted to find out what is the best solution. 
[image: first]
[image: two]
[image: three]
[image: four]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so much an answer as a bit of guidance to start with and some things for you to think about/answer.

The first thing to do is cut down all the overgrown grass and weeds, then you can see what you're dealing with, and it would be useful to see more pictures once you've done that. It does look as though any grass has a high percentage of weed; if its more weed than grass, it may be that you need to take it all up, decide where you want the lawn to be, prepare the area and lay new turf. However, given the difficulty in getting supplies for the garden currently, you may have to wait to do that till later. The angle of the sunlight makes it quite difficult to see the photos clearly too; the dark area in front of that door (what is that?) is impossible to view clearly to see what's there. Then clear away any clutter lying about if you don't want it, or gather it together somewhere out of the way if you do. Whatever that is hanging over the fence from next door needs cutting back too, can't tell what it is from the photo.

In respect of the wood base, take it up and get rid of it, that's the only way to get rid of the mice and rats (when you can, given the lockdown in the UK). Do you know if there's a hard base beneath, like concrete? Taking up the wood will reveal if there is anything else under there. Were you intending to have a shed? It looks to be a pretty small area, so knowing just how wide and long the main area is in terms of measurements would be helpful. Lastly, what's behind the green bin? There's light coming through there and I can't tell if it should have a fence because the other side is next door, or whether it's more of your garden behind it.

Comment: Behind the green bin is fences which will get changed as well as they have got rotten. As for the shed, We put a shed in middle of garden so if we take the base out it will be grass there too when I build lawn (not sure how would I take the base out as it might be infested)

Comment: pest control firm might be needed to clear the rats, pretty sure they're allowed to work currently,I wouldn't worry about the mice,but both these vermin do love wood (things like decking too) Depends how bad you think the rat problem is - if you don't corner them,they'll run away when you move the wood.

Comment: Rodents won't hang around if there is nowhere for them to live. But underneath your house, or in the roof space, will suit them just fine if they can find (or tunnel) a way in. After that, it's only a matter of time before they find a way into your kitchen or bathroom (e.g. by enlarging the holes in the floor made for pipes to pass through). Try to get all the rubbish (and wood) tidied up in summer, before they start looking for somewhere warm and dry to spend the winter!

Comment: I have updated the photos. Now got new fences and a trimmed the lawn too. It’s messy but hopefully will help to answer my question. I wanna have lush green grass

Comment: The turf is connected and I think growing beautifully . How long before someone can walk on ground? It’s been 1 week

Comment: You can walk lightly over it occasionally now, but for more normal use (not including dogs or children running about a lot)  its around 3 weeks. For kids playing, 4-6 weeks, but that depends on how well you care for it in terms of keeping it well watered, as well as how good the soil preparation was before laying . In good conditions, it should be fully rooted into the soil beneath after  6 weeks at this  time of year.